# How to load aws profile when logged via saml2aws inside a docker container?

Tags: python, docker, boto3

example contrived for the question. I login locally via saml2aws to generate access keys for my aws account and issue commands via aws-cli. once i login via SAML, i use a profile that i have set up to connect to resources in aws.  I am putting those commands in app.py file and adding a docker file with python and boto3 installed. from within the container, i need to access my_profile set up for aws in my local machine , how to access this or do i need to create/copy the aws credentials file to a container, if so how?

dockerfile

```
FROM python:alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual-dependencies python3 \
...
&& python3 -m ensurepip \ 
...
&& pip install boto3 ...
```

app.py

```
import boto3

my_session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name="my_profile")
aws_client = session.client('s3', region_name='us-east-1', config=...)
```

Comment: Does this process _have_ to run inside a container?  As you note it won't be able to access your host system's `.aws` directory or the `$AWS_...` environment variables.  If, say, a Python virtual environment is enough isolation for you, that might be easier to set up while still keeping access to normal host files.

Comment: @DavidMaze - yes, I want it to be able to run this in a container. is there a way we can copy the .aws/credentials file over and keep the same access and directory structure as in the local host